# Class weight adjustment in multi output model error

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to make a multi output model. I have 3 regression models (reg_1, reg_2, reg_3) and one classification model (cl_1) that classifies 5 classes (0,1,2,3,4). The classification data is not balanced, which is why I want to adjust the class weights.

My class weight parameters are:

```
class_weight = {"cl_1": {0: 1.837246564098982,
                         1: 0.6953029770433948,
                         2: 0.967228685544663,
                         3: 1.9681389026921166,
                         4: 0.6777320355514399
                         }
                }
```

I get an error when starting the model:

```
ValueError: Expected `class_weight` to be a dict with keys from 0 to one less than the number of classes, found {'cl_1: {0: 1.837246564098982, 1: 0.6953029770433948, 2: 0.967228685544663, 3: 1.9681389026921166, 4: 0.67773} }
```

---

I solved the problem by installing tensorflow version 2.1.0, since the same problem also occurred with version 2.2.0.

Is there any other solution using tensorflow 2.3.0?

Comment: following this question as I am stuck at the same issue.

Comment: It may not be the answer you want, but this will at least offer place to commiserate with those who have the same problem. It appears that class_weights with multiple output is a known deficiency. 
 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41448